# Корректно ли писать: «в своих соцсетях»?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Корректно ли писать: «*в своих соцсетях*»?

Есть мнение, что тут надо вставить «*на **своих страницах** в соцсетях*»:
мол, как соцсети могут быть своими, они же цукерберговские, дуровские, но не ваши.

Мне казалось, что у слова «соцсети» давно сформировались новые добавочные значения: «блог», «аккаунт», «личная страница».

Comment: Он ловит рыбу только в своих местах. Он закупается только в своих магазинах. Он общается только со своими людьми. ....

Comment: _В этих ваших интернетах_ и не такое корректно :)

Comment: @user190920 У вас только третий пример нормальный в плане стилистики. Но это другое значение: Относящийся к себе как члену какого-л. коллектива, какой-л. общности; связанный отношениями родства или общим местом работы, социальным положением, взглядами, вкусами и т.п. *Пойти в кино со своим классом. Вернуться после армии на свой завод. Стать в команде своим. Свой парень!* Это значение близко к "родной". А там личные страницы в соцсетях, уж точно не родные соцсети.

Comment: @user190920 - рыба попадается в сети, которые считает своими.

Answer (score -1):

Считаю, что это неправильно, и разделяю то мнение, которое вы косвенно осуждаете, но по другой причине. Соцсеть и личная страница - это разные вещи и их полезно различать. Если же вы будете воспринимать вторую как всего лишь "дополнительное значение" первой, то если не у вас, то у ваших читателей вскоре образуется каша (туман, винегрет) в голове. А ведь и без того известно, что нормальный результат всякого разговора - частичное взаимное недопонимание. Сокращать долю такого недопонимания - наша задача.
Я часто слышу, как пример такого неправильного словоупотребления подают дикторы радио и телевидения. Каждый раз меня коробит - как, впрочем, и от других их ляпов. Иногда мне то начинает казаться, что все они поголовно взяли на вооружение принцип театральных бездарностей: "Публика - дура, и так сойдёт!" То что с некоторых пор они стали заинтересованы в распространении тумана по нашим бедным головам.

Comment: Тяжело было читать ваш ответ, потому что он пропитан какой-то агрессией. Вы ошиблись, когда написали, что я осуждаю противоположную точку зрения. Дело в том, что я приемлю изменчивость языка и не отношу себя к пуристам. Мой вопрос был задан не с укором, а с просьбой разъяснить — так, чтобы было аргументированное мнение с опорой на источники, а не фразы в духе: «это неправильно, потому что меня бесит».

Comment: @Media median,, извините. Это всего лишь полемика, и я вовсе не хотел вас обидеть. Я привёл свои доводы.